# Invalid data in LYNQ L510

Tags: c, embedded, gps

I am trying to get latitude and longitude and i am using L510(LYNQ), I try to get "AT" commands for it but i failed.

I got a command "AT+MGPSC=1" and response is:-

```
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,E,N*08
$GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,127.00,,,,,,*62
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,127.00,127.00,127.00*04
$BDGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,127.00,127.00,127.00*15
$GLGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,127.00,127.00,127.00*18
$GNGLL,,,,,,V,N*7A
$GNZDA,,,,,00,00*56
$GNGST,,,,,,,,*49
$GNTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=UNKNOWN*69
$HOSTSLEEP
```

My requirement:- To get Latituide and Longitude.

I tried command:- "AT+MGPSC=1"

Comment: What is your L510? A quick web research seems to tell that is is "just" a GSM modem, not a GPS receiver. So where should the position data come from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine the Lynq L510 is a GSM modem not a GNSS receiver.  I have no idea under what circumstances it can resolve a position if at all, but clearly it has not done so in your case.

Longitude, latitude, COG, SOG, time-of-day (UTC), and date are provided in (at least), the RMC sentence.  In your example the relevant fields in the RMC are null (no data available).

```
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,E,N*08
        \           \_ Mode Indicator - N=Data not valid
         \         
          \_ Data Invalid
```

This is not a software issue.  The module has simply not yet acquired a fix.  And I have doubts that it is even able to do so.  Possibly it is a common AT command across products and is simply responding to this one with null data.  And "not valid" is the permanent state.

Comment: I am using LYNQ L510 module and i want to get Latitude and longitude by using AT Commands. I tried to find out documentation for AT commands but i did not get . Can you please help me to get latitude and longitude.

Comment: @VinayR.Tiwari repeating your question in a comment will not make the answer any different.  What makes you believe that the L510 is capable of providing location information? Nothing in any documentation I can find suggests it can.  Even if it can, there is a text message indicating antenna status "unknown".  If you have no antenna, well, that may be your problem.  Even if it acquires position by tower triangulation and not GNSS, you would still need a connection to those towers, and possibly a service provision (I don't know, it is beyond my knowledge and off-topic here in any case)